# I can't put a state from the upper scope inside a function with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm struggling to put a state inside a function without parameters as a reference(if I understand it correctly).

I have an event class that has methods close and open. By default, these methods don't do anything(besides throwing an error about missing functionality) until you assign them callbacks via **assignOpenCallback** and **assignCloseCallback** where you define their behaviour from "outside".

```
export class Event {
    constructor({ id, coordinates, content }: EventConstructor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public id: EventID;

    public coordinates: EventCoordinates;
    public content: EventData;

    public isSelected: boolean = false;

    public clickAction: ClickEventAction = () => {
        if (this.isSelected) return this.close();
        return this.open();
    }

    //Defining of methods from outside
    public assignCloseCallback = (callback: () => void) => this.close = () => callback();
    public assignOpenCallback = (callback: () => void) => this.open = () => callback();

    public close: CloseEventAction = () => { // <--- This
        throw new Error("Close event functionality isn't assigned.");
    }

    public open: OpenEventAction = () => { // <--- And this
        throw new Error("Open event functionality isn't assigned.");
    }
}
```

I use the state **selectedEvent** which is keeping the selected event by a user and sending this state to other components.

```
//State of all available events
const [events, setEvents] = useState<Array<Event>>([]);
//State of selected event
const [selectedEvent, setSelectedEvent] = useState<SelectedEvent>(null);
```

I define the behaviour of mentioned methods in the useEffect hook with empty array dependency which imitates API data fetching to describe logic when the user clicks on the event and there I use **selectedEvent** state for a case when the event was changed without actually closing the event(while event open and the user has been opened another event).

```
const closeEvent = (event: Event) => {
    console.log(selectedEvent);
    setSelectedEvent(null);
    event.isSelected = false;
}

const openEvent = (event: Event) => {
    console.log(selectedEvent)
    if (selectedEvent) selectedEvent.close();
    setSelectedEvent(event);
    event.isSelected = true;
}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const loadedEvents = fakeResponse.events;

    const events = loadedEvents.map(loadedEvent => {
        const { id, content, coordinates } = loadedEvent;
        const event = new Event({ id, content, coordinates });

        event.assignCloseCallback(() => closeEvent(event));
        event.assignOpenCallback(() => openEvent(event));

        return event;
    });

    setEvents(events);
}, []);
```

And the problem is that these functions always refer to the initial value of the state which is null regardless of the real state.

I'm a little bit frustrated because I even don't know where the problem is.

I'm a novice in React so any advice would be helpfull.

Comment: Well, your `useEffect` is only executed once when the component renders the first time. That's what passing an empty dependency array means. Any futures changes to `selectedEvent` won't have any effect. So either make the dependencies explicit so that the effect is executed again whenever one of the dependencies changes, or use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) so that the functions can always refer to the *current* selected event whenever the functions are executed. Which one to choose kind of depends on the bigger picture.